# Find the square root of a term with a variable

Tags: exponentiation, radicals

I'm reviewing a PSAT score report with my son and trying to account for the College Board's answer.

Below are the question and answer. I follow them as far as:
$$
\sqrt{8r^2}
$$

From that point, I would simplify something like this:
$$
\sqrt{2(2^2)(r^2)}
$$
$$
2r\sqrt{2}
$$

But the answer is:

$$
2\sqrt{2r}
$$

I don't understand how the square root of $r^2$ becomes the square root of r.

Please explain or point me to an explanation online. I'm clearly no mathematician.

[image: Diagram of circles]
[image: Question and answer choices]
[image: Answer]

Comment: The printed answer is wrong; your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Just looks like a typo. You are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a printing error;

usually one write $\sqrt{8} = 2\sqrt{2}$, so $\sqrt{8r^2} = 2\sqrt 2 r $ may easily have become $2\sqrt{2r}$

Comment: I agree. This is the most likely scenario. You're reasoning is correct and Ant's idea here is a good one.

Comment: And this is why good mathematical typography avoids writing expressions like $2\sqrt2r$ and prefers to put the surd last, as $2r\sqrt 2$.

Comment: My son often hopes for a mistake in the answer key. He'll be delighted. Thanks for the prompt and clear response.

Comment: @MichaelH you're very welcome :)